# Nativescript application crashes with "Encountered undefined provider!" before module loaded on IOS but works on Android

Tags: nativescript

I am using nativescript  5.1.1 with android version 5.1.0 and ios version 5.1.1. When the application starts on ios it immediately crashes with the following error: 
JavaScript stack trace:

1   _reportError@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19223:31
2   @file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19072:43
3   forEach@[native code]
4   _getProvidersMetadata@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19057:30
5   getNgModuleMetadata@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18776:84
6   _loadModules@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26060:74
7   _compileModuleAndComponents@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26041:52
8   compileModuleAsync@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:26001:68
9   bootstrapModule@file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:17836:42
10  _bootstrapper@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:87:50
11  @file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js:150:32
12  notify@file:///app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/data/observable/o<…>

JavaScript error:
file:///app/tns_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:19223:31: JS ERROR Error: Encountered undefined provider! Usually this means you have a circular dependencies. This might be caused by using 'barrel' index.ts files.

Additionally when looking at the console from the device i see this. 
[19-02-08 11:56:23.932] (CLI) (node:39256) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'pipe' of undefined
    at WebSocketServer.server.on (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/lib/device-sockets/ios/app-debug-socket-proxy-factory.js:124:32)
    at WebSocketServer.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at handleUpgrade (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:79:18)
    at WebSocketServer.completeUpgrade (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:293:5)
    at options.verifyClient (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/nativescript/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket-server.js:210:16)

This doesn't seem to be in my module because it runs properly in Android.

I'm mainly looking for some help in debugging the issue. I don't have any way to debug the dynamic code being pushed to the emulator or phone.

Comment: Does this happen even in a fresh new project or just with yours?

Comment: It doesn't happen with a fresh project. It only started happening after updating the nativescript version. I'm stuck trying to figure out what broke during the update.

Comment: Did you try removing your plugins & comment related code one by one, may be it would help you to find if it's a issue with some plugin as it works on Android already.

Comment: I'm in the process of doing that now, thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What are the versions of the following packages:
 nativescript-angular, nativescript-dev-webpack and angular?

You mentioned you updated nativescript but maybe you should update the above mentioned packages as well.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was an import of the AndroidApplication class without a platform check. The error that was thrown was just not great. If someone else comes across this perhaps that will help.